# System of linear equations with parameters, using a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let there be the following system of linear equations: 
$$x+z+bw=a \\
ax+y+az+(a+ab)w=1+a^2 \\
bx+(a+b)z+(1+b^2)w=4+a\\
bx+bz+(a-ab+b^2)w=a+1+ab$$

a,b parameters. The question is, for which a,b there is no solution to the system, for which there are infinite and for which there is one. I put it into a matrix and with some row operations I got to: 
$$\begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 0 & 1 & b&a \\
0&1&0&a&1\\
0&0&a&1&4\\
0&0&0&a-2b&a+1 \end{array}$$

How do I continue from here? I'm quite confused. For instance I thought that saying that for all b, if a=2b then there is no solution. But that doesn't sound quite right...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done good until that row reduced form (I assume the calculations are correct).

Now, if $a=0$, you can do another row operation:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & b&0 \\
0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&4\\
0&0&0&-2b&1 \end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1 & 0 & 1 & b&0 \\
0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&4\\
0&0&0&0&1+8b \end{array}\right]
$$
What can you say about this case?

If, instead, $a\ne0$, you have to distinguish when $a-2b=0$ or not.

If $a-2b=0$ you have $a=2b$ and you have a solution if and only if $a+1=0$, that is $a=-1$ and $b=-2$.

If $a-2b\ne0$, then …

Comment: Thank you very much, haven't thought of that this way!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Calculate the determinant of the matrix of coefficients and find those $a,b$ for which it equals $0$.

Comment: Hi, it is to be solved without determinants. Thanks again!